# Need help to solve nodejs module.exports throws error

Tags: javascript, node.js, module.exports

I have user route as below and I am importing controller in user.routes.js

```
//user.routes.js

const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const userController = require('../controllers/user.controller')

router.get('/info', userController.getUser)

module.exports = router
```

Below is how I have declared user controller

```
//user.controller.js

const {wrapController} = require("../ErrorHandlers/catchError");
const {Api404Error} = require("../ErrorHandlers/apiErrors");

function userController() {
    const controller = {
        getUser(req, res) {
            throw new Api404Error('User not found.') //I did small correction here
        }
    }
    wrapController(controller)
    return controller
}

module.exports = userController
```

But I am getting this error.

```
Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
```

I am new to Nodejs.
Thanks for helping.

Comment: There is no `getUser()` definition in your `user.controller.js`.

Comment: @rustyhu Sorry i am not sure that i should define it in another way but there is `getUser` in `user.Controller.js`

Comment: getUser is not defined under `userController.getUser`. Its part of `controller` in userController.

Comment: @PardeepDhingra can you please give example how to do it? and what will be difference?

Comment: try `wrapController(controller.getUser)` . I see that you pass `controller` into `wrapController` but thats a variable holding an object. You did not pass a function into it.

Comment: You should export the function call. Change `module.exports = userController` to `module.exports = userController()`

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV Thanks for helping out. it works if I change it like however you said `module.exports = userController()`